# Update if the field is null else ignore

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update the `test_cert_date` field if the `batch_id` and `sr_no` is present in the `inq_prod_dates` table else need to insert the row.

**Example:**

inq_prod_dates :

| id | batch_id | sr_no | test_cert_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 20-05-2021 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |  |

1. If passing `batch_id` as  2 and `sr_no` as 3 to the mysql query, need to check if the `test_cert_date` field has any value with this combination in table,  if value is empty then only I need to perform the update else Ignore.
2. If the `batch_id` and `sr_no` combination is not present in the table, then need to insert the row.

```
CREATE TABLE `inq_prod_dates` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `batch_id` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `sr_no` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `test_cert_date` tinytext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

I tried with the below query, but new row is getting inserted even if the `batch_id` and `sr_no` combination is present in the table.

```
INSERT INTO inq_prod_dates (batch_id, sr_no, test_cert_date)
                        VALUES('2', '3','20-05-2021')
                        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE test_cert_date = IF(test_cert_date IS NULL, '20-05-2021', test_cert_date)
```

Comment: You have not unique key on batch_id and sr_no, according to your shown create table.

Comment: @FranCerezo In some cases, either batch_id or sr_no can be null, that's why I didn't add unique key for those.

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` cannot act without at least one UNIQUE index (which may, but not must, be primary key). *In some cases, either batch_id or sr_no can be null, that's why I didn't add unique key for those.* Column nullability does not interfere with UNIQUE index creation. The row where NULL is present won't be checked for uniqueness simply. At the same time these columns are defined as NOT NULL, so they cannot be NULL.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for the explanation. The batch_id and sr_no combination will be unique, in that case, I can add unique key to both fileds right?

Comment: Yes, add composite unique index (remember - for TEXT datatype you MUST specify indexed prefix length). Then use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE test_cert_date = COALESCE(test_cert_date, '2021-05-20')` (pay attention, MySQL accepts only YYYY-MM-DD date literal format).

Comment: @Akina I've tried your suggestion, now the duplicate entries are not happening, but the update is not triggering when the test_cert_date field is null for the available combination in the table.

Comment: @Akina I've added the updated table structure in the question.

Comment: @Hello Screenshot cannot be copypasted for the table creation - provide textual CREATE TABLE script. Also add some sample data, query (present) and desired result after indsertion.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Akina, FranCerezo . The issue is fixed by adding composite unique key with the same query mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is fixed by adding composite unique key as below:

```
ADD UNIQUE KEY `batch` (`batch_id`,`sr_no`) USING HASH;
```